# Bromination on aromatic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, electronic-configuration

[image]

So guys, very quick question: Why does bromination occur at exactly this position on the aromatic ring? Has it something to do with the substituents and their respective electronic effects?

Comment: Bromination (in fact any Electrophilic aromatic substitution) occurs at ortho/para to electron donating groups. Generally ortho-product is lesser (except special stabilisation casese like Hydrogen Bonding etc.) due to steric factor. Para is generally the major product which is the case here also due to electron donating $\ce{N}$ directly attached to Benzene ring.

Comment: To follow up @SoumikDas, you've got essentially an N,N-dimethylamino group which is making it difficult to access the unsubstituted ortho position.